# Law of large numbers and identically distributed variables

Tags: probability-theory

I have trouble understanding the need of the "identically distributed variables" hypothesis in laws of large number's type theorem.

For example, here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeakLawofLargeNumbers.html there is a demonstration of the weak law of large numers.
I don't understand why the hypothesis of same mean and same deviation isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. You also don't need identical deviation. Consider for example the proof using Chebyshev's inequality. Suppose that the mean and variance of $X_i$ are $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i^2$, and that $\frac{1}{n}(\mu_1+\cdots+\mu_n) \to \mu$. For every $\epsilon > 0$,
$$
\Pr\left[\left|\frac{X_1-\mu_1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{X_n-\mu_n}{n}\right| > \epsilon\right] < \frac{\sigma_1^2+\cdots+\sigma_n^2}{n^2\epsilon}.
$$
As long as $\frac{1}{n}(\sigma_1^2+\cdots+\sigma_n^2) = o(n)$, the weak law will hold.

We get the following theorem. Suppose that $X_i$ has mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$, that the average mean tends to $\mu$, and that the $n$th average variance is $o(n)$. Then the average tends in distribution to $\mu$.

Comment: What does motivate the use of the "identical distribution" hypothesis in the classicals proofs of thoses laws, if you could have better for the same proof ? History ? Or the fact that we don't usualy need better ?

Comment: The idea of the law of large numbers is that the expectation is what you get when you average a large number of copies of your random variable. The method of the proof can be used to prove other results.